# Python : formating query for Google Suggest

Tags: python

the code does not work with multiple keywords at the same time

Ex. keyword1 keyword2 keyword3 referral to bad URL formatting:

```
/get_all_related/keyword1%20keyword2%20keyword3
```

instead of this

```
/get_all_related/keyword1+keyword2+keyword3
```

How to get URL formatting as desired?

here the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

import json
import sys
import urllib.request

app = Flask(__name__)

url = 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q={}'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def get_related(entity):
    search_term = quote_plus('{} vs '.format(entity))
    request = urllib.request.Request(url.format(search_term))
    result = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    suggestions = json.loads(result.read())
    return [x.replace(suggestions[0],'') for x in suggestions[1] if 'vs' not in x.replace(suggestions[0],'')]
```

Thank's for help

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I wish to format url like this: keyword1+keyword2+keyword3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `search_term` has any spaces in it, they will be converted to `%20` when calling a function to encode for URI (`url.format()`). You will have to replace them with + before encoding into a URL safe format:

`request = urllib.request.Request(url.format(search_term.replace(' ','+')))`

This will replace all spaces with +, then encode the entire string as URI safe.